# Change user-type in API Header or change header using variable

Tags: android, string, retrofit, final

I declare a final variable in global

`public static final  String USERTYPE="customer"`

Then I use this variable as

```
@POST
@Headers({
        "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Cache-Control: max-age=640000",
        "user-type: " + APIService.STRING
})
Call<ReturnPojo> addpost(@Url String s, @Body Add body);
```

Later in my program, I need to change the

`USERTYPE="guest"`

I try

```
1.USERTYPE.replace("customer","guest");

2.String user="customer"
  USERTYPE=user;
```

How can I achieve this? or How to change a final variable in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Header on Run-time(Retrofit API)

We cannot change the final variable, So we cannot change the user type programmatically. By duplicating the code is not good practice. But we can be done through this,

```
@POST
Call<ReturnPojo> addpost(@Url String s,
        @Body Add body,
        @Header("user-type") String user_type,
        @Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
        @Header("Accept") String accept,
        @Header("Cache-Control") String cache_controller);
```

And finally, while we call API just pass the data as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You've declared USERTYPE as final so the only choice you have is to use a different String.

Comment: How to use a different String in interface 
        "user-type: " + APIService.STRING

Comment: Just declare a second addPost method that references whatever string value you want